# Prove that 2m + 3n = 0 (mod 5) is an equivalence relation on the integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, equivalence-relations

The relation on $\mathbb{Z}$, given by m ~ n iff 2m+3n $\equiv$ 0 (mod 5). How do you prove that this is an equivalence relation?

I got that it is reflexive so far, but I am stuck on if it is symmetric.

Comment: The "brute force" method would be to break it up into cases... ie $n\equiv 0, \dots, 4 $

Comment: It might be worth noting that you can rearrange that condition to $2m \equiv -3n\pmod{5}$ or, equivalently, $2m \equiv 2n\pmod{5}$ - there's still a few details to figure out, depending on how much you've already shown about equivalence relations, but this observations leads to more general insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show symmetry ($n\sim m \iff m\sim n$):

$2n+3m\equiv0\pmod5$

$\iff4(2n+3m)\equiv0\pmod5$

$\iff8n+12m\equiv0\pmod5$

$\iff 3n+2m=2m+3n\equiv0\pmod5$

Comment: to show transitivity, $2m+3n\equiv0$ and $2n+3k\equiv0 \implies 4m+6n\equiv0$ and $6n+9k\equiv0\implies 4m-9k\equiv0\implies 4m+k\equiv0\implies 3(4m+k)\equiv0\implies 2m+3k\equiv0$

Comment: Forgot to mark it as the right answer, just made sure to do that! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  I hope you saw the good comment of Milo Brandt above too